# Set up a generic proxy pass rule on apache

Tags: ajax, apache, proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

I'm trying to hit my rest service running locally on

```
http://localhost:8080
```

with an ajax request as such

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/api/test",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(testData) {
        callback(testData);
    }
});
```

Where I get the json data back from

```
http://localhost:8080/api/test.
```

This works fine if I add this rule to my http.conf file

```
ProxyPass /api/test http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

However I have mutiple endpoints I would like to hit at

```
http://localhost:8080/api/*
```

Is there a general rule I can add that will allow me to hit everything at /api/* without having to enter in a separate rule for every endpoint like this:

```
ProxyPass /api/test/foo http://localhost:8080/api/test/foo
ProxyPass /api/bar http://localhost:8080/api/bar
etc.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you replace

```
ProxyPass /api/test http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

by

```
ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8080/api
```

then anything that starts with /api will be correctly redirected.